# Android Studio gradle sync failed to find library

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-library, build.gradle

So I'm working on project in AndroidStudio 0.8.1 beta and I want to make use of a library I found on github (https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers). I add the dependency like it says inside the README.md but when I try to sync the project with the gradle files it says:

> Failed to find: com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.2

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'gtsarandum.syncc'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile project(':extendedCalendarView')
    compile project(':src')
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.7.3'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library-extra:1.7.3'
    compile 'com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.2'
}
```

Last time I had this problem with `gabriellemariotti.cards:libraryd:1.7.3` I added `maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }` inside the buildscript as you can see above.

Is there something else I have to add? If not, how do I solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try alter 'gradle.settings' with an include statement for the path/lib not being found.

Comment: actually I just had to turn off offline mode in the gradle settings :|

Comment: @NDTS Turning off offline mode worked for me too, thank you. Android Studio can sure be quite frustrating sometimes ..

Comment: Indeed.. offline mode can be such a b**ch,

Answer (score 4):

My fix was to add:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

to the build.gradle file

Comment: Use `jcenter` instead of `mavenCentral`. The new default repository of Android Stuido is `jcenter`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use HTTP Proxy. Android Studio -> File -> Settings-> HTTP Proxy -> No proxy